# switching part of a button option to be a radio

Tags: php, html, radio-button

Okay guys so my problem here is I need to show some pictures of colors that people can use to pick the color of a cover.  Right now its set up to be a drop down and just select the color but we want to switch it over to be the colors.

Here is the code we have set up right now.

```
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">


            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {    ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" 
            <?php if(array_key_exists('poid', $_REQUEST)) { ?>
            <?php if($option_value['product_option_value_id']==$_REQUEST['poid']){ echo "selected"; }}?>>

            <?php echo $option_value['name'];    ?>


            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?>
            <?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>

            <?php } ?>
          </select>
```

And this is what I've come up with so far.

```
        <?php if ($options) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($options as $option) {  ?>
        <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {  

        //echo $option_value['image']; 

        if($option_value['image']){    ?>

        <div class="button">
        <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" />
        <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']?>" />
        <label "<?php echo $option_value['name'];?>" </label>
        </div>



       <?php }}} }?>
```

Another concern is we have other button options that need to keep working for other selections.

Comment: What's your question? Is the new code working? If not, what is it doing wrong?

Comment: So the new code shows up but I need it to produce the exact same answer if you were to click the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<label>` syntax is wrong. It should produce:

```
<label for="button ID">Name</label>
```

but you're printing:

```
<label "Name" </label>
```

Or you can simply wrap a `<label>` tag around both the button and the name, as I've done below.

```
    <div class="button">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
    <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']?>" />
    <?php echo $option_value['name'];?>
    </label>
    </div>
```

I got rid of the `id` on the button because it was creating duplicate IDs on all the buttons in the same radio group, and is probably not needed.

Other than that problem, I think it should work.